# Mailchimp: Register user via API: can't set a custom field

Tags: node.js, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

My NodeJS backend communicates with the Mailchimp API (v3) in order to register new subscribers. I'm unable to find the value that allows setting a simple "YES" or "NO" in this case.

From the list settings UI, here is my custom field:
[image]

The following code properly registers the user but the custom "WEB3JS" field isn't set (with *npm install mailchimp-api-v3* installed).

What could I be doing wrong?

```
var Mailchimp = require('mailchimp-api-v3')
var mailchimp = new Mailchimp(/* API key */);

return function handler(req, res){

    const email = req.body.email;
    const name = req.body.name;
    const web3 = req.body.web3;

    const body = {
        email_address : email,
        status : 'subscribed'
    };

    body.WEB3JS = web3 ? 'YES' : 'NO';
    body.WEB3JS = 'YES'; // Debug: force "yes"

    mailchimp.post('/lists/**LIST_ID**/members', body)
        .then(function(results) {
            res.json({});
        })
```

Comment: Not familiar with MailChimp, but shouldn't this field go in to a `merge_fields` sub-object or something similar?

Comment: The JSON of the response should give a hint...

Comment: Please provide the response.